# 50k static html pages to generate on .net MVC website - how does this work with continuous deployment?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, caching, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

Here's the situation.

1. Our website has about 50,000 "detail" pages, each made up of a number of chunks of data from our database and APIs. Currently these are dynamic, but the data only needs to change daily, if that. We have enabled output caching to speed things up.
2. We deploy to Appharbor multiple times a day direct from Git. Do correct me if I'm wrong, but I think we lose the cache every time we do that. So output caching isn't doing all it should. Besides which, I'd rather the content was cached from the start rather than when the first user hits each page.

Now, if it were not for the continuous deployment issue I would suggest generating static html files during compilation for maximum performance. But I feel like churning through that process a number of times a day can't be the right solution.

What caching strategy should we be looking at?

Side question: if we do generate 50k static html files, would you arrange them on disk as a folder structure somehow or store them in a database, or in memory, or what?

Comment: Surely the caching should be as transparent as possible. You say that you have enabled Output Caching, but you don't mention at what level you output cache, ASP.Net MVC/IIS/Dynamic Content Compression?

Comment: PS Consider how storing your static html on a (singleton like) database (with limited I/O) would affect your situation?

Comment: First question: do you actually have a performance problem?

Comment: @ZippyV Not at the moment. I'm just exploring options.

Comment: @Aron we've enabled output caching in the mvc application, on the Action that generates the html for the detail view. I'm afraid don't understand what you mean by a singleton like database.

Comment: @centralscru The Database is often overlooked as a form of the Singleton pattern. The one true place to look up data. If you consider that in most highly scaled systems the database IO is the first to suffer you will realize that offloading your data storage to the database means you can't scale out. Generally speaking I try to move everything OFF the database for performance, where you can parallelise your IO onto each application host's HDD.

Comment: How much traffic do you have on your website?

Comment: You should consider enabling dynamic compression on IIS. As an upshot of the compression caching you will actually use less storage on IIS per page AND each page will take up less bandwidth (assuming your clients can accept gzip).

Comment: @Aron not sure whether dynamic compression is an option at Appharbor (or maybe it's on by default). Offloading from the db is exactly what I have in mind; so are you talking about writing files to the file system? Not sure what practical solution you're hinting at.

Comment: @ZippyV No traffic at all: we haven't launched yet. While I do apply the YAGNI principle it strikes me that since we're hitting our db at RavenHQ for every detail page, and the detail pages will likely make up the large majority of our traffic, it seems rather unnecessary to make that call to RavenHQ.

Comment: @centralscru, I wasn't actually hinting at a solution in that comment. In your last sentence in your OP you considered caching your (output) files to the database. Which I advised against as an anti pattern.

Comment: @Aron - ah, ok, I'm with you. Thanks!

Comment: Oh wow, you are using RavenDb as opposed to an RDBMS. In that case, go right ahead and store your cache in there. However, given the latency of the hosted DB perhaps a mash up solution could be best. If you are doing very little processing with MVC, you could in theory just use a static details page with some Knockout.js or jQuery to template up the page and load the data straight from Raven (since its already JSON). This will of course open up the RavenDB, and could be potentially a security risk...

Comment: @centralscru My application hits the database multiple times for each page load. Why don't you try some load testing on your test server and see how far you can go with using no caching at all and then using MVC's OutputCache.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use App Fabric Cache ? (I don't know if it's available through app harbor)

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingConfiguringAndUsingWindowsServerAppFabricAndTheVelocityMemoryCacheIn10Minutes.aspx

Or maybe you should think about implementing your own OutputCache Provider and save the result in your ravendb or in the file system :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg650661.aspx

This way you can ensure the cache is not cleared when you restart the app.

EDIT : app fabric is not available but  you can use memcache with this provider : https://github.com/enyim/memcached-providers